# Apple MacBook Air display problem

Tags: display

I have 2017  MacBook Air and it shows display problem           it did not fell but I dont know how this problem has come please help[image]

Comment: Your display is broken - take it in for service.

Comment: Thanxx for your help I just want to ask how it is possible if it did not fell

Comment: Something could have dropped *onto* it.  Or something heavy placed on it.  Or inadvertently hit by something.  There's physical damage, so *something* physically happened to it.

Comment: That looks like the kind of damage you get when you close the lid with something left on the keyboard - headset/ear bud etc.

Answer (score 3):

Just to provide an answer...

The screen appears to have had an impact roughly where I've circled below. This could have been caused by a strike, but equally could be that something was on the keyboard when the lid was closed.

The initial impact has cracked the screen out in radial lines from the impact site, causing the circuitry in the screen to break along the lines - this is why there is no image above them; data cannot transmit across the broken circuit.

[image]

Comment: Thanxx for your effort

Comment: It’s a shame that damage is needed to explain visually how the lcd panel works, but that’s a great description.